# reading avro compressed data with snappy generates an error of "snappy codec decompression error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, avro, snappy

I have an application (KafkaConnect) that is generating me avro files into S3.
This files are compressed with avro code "snappy".
I'm trying to read them with javascript (I'm not a very strong javascript developer as you will be able to guess).

I tried to use [avro-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avro-js) or [avsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avsc) as libraries to help me with this since they are referenced in most of the online examples I found for doing this.
The most complete example and very useful I found was [here](https://medium.com/@frankbaele/avro-containers-in-nodejs-95b72cbdde90).

Anyway it seems most examples I found are using [snappy version 6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snappy) which seems to be a bit different than version 7 (the latest).
One of the main things I noticed is that it now provides two methods of uncompress. One with sync and another which returns a promise, but none that can receive a call back function.

Anyway I think this is not an issue because I could make it work regardless, but my best example to read this files would be something like this (with avsc).

```
const avsc = require('avsc');
const avsc = require('avsc');
const snappy = require('snappy');
const codecs = {
  snappy: function (buf, cb) {
  // Avro appends checksums to compressed blocks, which we skip here.
    const buffer = snappy.uncompressSync(buf.slice(0, buf.length - 4));
    return cb(buffer);
  }
};
avsc.createFileDecoder('person-10.snappy.avro', {codecs})
  .on('metadata', function (writerType) {
    console.log(writerType.name);
  })
  .on('data', function (obj) {
    console.log('on data ');
    console.log('obj');
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('end');
  });
```

Anyway the processing of metadata works without issues (I can access the full schema information) but the data always fails with
`Uncaught Error: snappy codec decompression error`

I'm looking for someone that has by some reason worked with avro and snappy in the latest versions and managed to make this work.

Because I'm really struggling with understanding this I created a fork of the official avsc repo and tried to introduce my examples there to see how this work but if more useful I could try and create a simpler
[reproducible scenario.](https://github.com/cstmgl/avsc/blob/test-load-file/test/test_index.js#L109)

Answer (score 0):

the documentation of the package I was using was updated and now the problem is fixed.

https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/API#class-blockdecoderopts

mainly I was just wrong on how to call the call back function and how to handle the buffer to snappy.

this is the correct way (as documented)

```
const crc32 = require('buffer-crc32');
const snappy = require('snappy');

const blockDecoder = new avro.streams.BlockDecoder({
  codecs: {
    snappy: (buf, cb) => {
      // Avro appends checksums to compressed blocks.
      const len = buf.length;
      const checksum = buf.slice(len - 4, len);
      snappy.uncompress(buf.slice(0, len - 4))
        .then((inflated) => {
          if (!checksum.equals(crc32(inflated))) {
            // We make sure that the checksum matches.
            throw new Error('invalid checksum');
          }
          cb(null, inflated);
        })
        .catch(cb);
    }
  }
});
```